# How can my Gradle plugin define a task depending on a task of AGP 7.0.0?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have written a Gradle plugin based on Android Gradle Plugin: for each variant, the plugin defines a task `generate`*variant*`Stuff` that generates an asset and I need that the `merge`*variant*`Assets` (defined by AGP) takes my asset as an input, so the `merge`*variant*`Assets` task must depend on my `generate`*variant*`Stuff` task.
My plugin works properly with AGP 4.2.2.

AGP 7.0.0 deprecates `com.android.build.gradle.api.ApplicationVariant` and replaces it by `com.android.build.api.variant.ApplicationVariant`, so that I have to replace also `com.android.build.gradle.AppExtension` by `com.android.build.api.variant.ApplicationAndroidComponentsExtension` and the loop on the variants.
Now, when Android Studio builds the model, it fails with the following error:

```
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Task with name 'mergeDebugAssets' not found in project ':app'.
```

But in Gradle view of Android Studio a can see the `mergeDebugAssets` task.
It seems that during the method `AppExtension.getApplicationVariants().all()` (AGP 4.2.2), AGP has already defined its tasks, while, during the method `ApplicationAndroidComponentsExtension.onVariants()` (AGP 7.0.0), AGP has not yet defined its tasks.

You can see sample code at https://gist.github.com/dscoppelletti/d4ca0e1a19ed4ba4aaea99cf48ae930a

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I have similar issues with it. I have an aggregated task that collects artifacts from each variant and copies them to a given path, but assemble tasks for variants are not available during `ApplicationAndroidComponentsExtension.onVariants()`